# How to reach Linux API

Tags: linux, api

I am new here.

I want to ask about Linux API
I have used winapi, win32api and their libraries like user32.dll

Is there LinuxAPI and how can I reach it.
and I will be grateful if there is an example in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is only a kernel whereas Windows is both a kernel and a GUI.

Linux should generally be accessed through the standard C library.  For doing GUI things, look into Qt, GTK, wxWidgets, or any of several others.  If you're a sucker for punishment, you can use the X11 interface directly.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Linux is a lot more loosely coupled as a result of the "Tools not Policy" philosophy. The kernel itself exposes a bunch of system calls available through assembly code or the slightly more convenient C library. Everything else will be fully dependent on the stack of technologies that form your particular distribution. The short answer is that there exists no federated API like in windows rather numerous API's cobbled together to form the User Experience.